# Can I use a for loop that shifts in 1 new bit each iteration to get some 8-bit number in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, bit-shift

I am working on implementing an ***8-bit adder*** abstracted with code in Java. This 8-bit adder is built from 8 ***full adder*** circuits. For those who don't know what a full adder is, it's a circuit that computes the sum of 2 bits.

My intention was to use a for loop to add each corresponding bit of the adders 2, 8-bit inputs, such that a new bit of the 8-bit result is computed each time the for loop iterates.

***Would it be possible to store the new computed bit of each iteration in a variable holding the 8-bit result using bit shifting?***

Here's an example to help explain what I am asking. *The bold bit would be the one that is shifted into the int holding the result.*

> 0b00001010

+

> 0b00001011

**Initial State**

> Sum: 0
>
> Result: 0b00000000
>
> Carry: 0

**First Iteration (addition starting w/ LSB)**

> Sum: 1
>
> Result: 0b0000000**1**
>
> Carry: 0

**Second Iteration**

> Sum: 0
>
> Result: 0b000000**0**1
>
> Carry: 1

**Third Iteration**

> Sum: 1
>
> Result: 0b00000**1**01
>
> Carry: 0

**Fourth Iteration**

> Sum: 0
>
> Result: 0b0000**0**101
>
> Carry: 1

**Fifth Iteration**

> Sum: 1
>
> Result: 0b000**1**0101
>
> Carry: 0

**Sixth, Seventh, Eigth Iteration**

> Sum: 0, 0, 0 respectively
>
> Result: 0b**000**10101
>
> Carry: 0, 0, 0 respectively

Comment: ..... are you actually asking how to assign a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are starting the computation at the least significant bit end and progress toward the most significant bit end as you go, you need an operation to *place* a bit in `n`-th position, as opposed to shifting in a bit<sup>*</sup>.

Placing `n`-th bit in an initially zeroed value is simple - you shift `1` left by `n`, and then OR the shifted value with the result, like this:

```
int value = 0;
int n = 3;
int valueWithNthBitSet = value | (1 << n);
```

At this point, `valueWithNthBitSet` is equal to `b00000100`.

You can apply this trick repeatedly to place the results that you get from your full adders into the bits of the result:

```
int res = 0;
int a = 10;
int b = 11;
int carry = 0;
for (int bit = 0 ; i != 8 ; i++) {
    int aBit = getBit(a, i);
    int bBit = getBit(a, i);
    int resBit = fullAdderGetResultBit(aBit, bBit, carry);
    carry = fullAdderGetCarryBit(aBit, bBit, carry);
    if (resBit == 1) {
        res |= 1 << i;
    }
}
```

When the loop is over, the result would be equal to the two values added together.

<sup>*</sup> Shifting in would apply if you started at the MSB and progressed toward LSB as you go.